# Cron won't stop running

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have Aoe Scheduler on Magento and noticed that "system backup" is still running for almost a day. I tried killing the process using the kill option in Aoe Scheduler and get this in my log file:

```
2015-12-22T18:33:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 467
2015-12-22T18:34:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 453
2015-12-22T18:34:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 453
2015-12-22T18:34:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 467
2015-12-22T18:34:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 467
2015-12-22T18:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 453
2015-12-22T18:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: posix_kill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given  in /home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php on line 453
```

The file Schedule.php has this:

```
    // let's be nice first (a.k.a. "Could you please stop running now?")
    if (posix_kill($this->getPid(), SIGINT)) {
        $this->log(sprintf('Sending SIGINT to job "%s" (id: %s)', $this->getJobCode(), $this->getId()));
    } else {
        $this->log(sprintf('Error while sending SIGINT to job "%s" (id: %s)', $this->getJobCode(), $this->getId()), Zend_Log::ERR);
    }

    // check if process terminates within 30 seconds
    $startTime = time();
    while (($waitTime = (time() - $startTime) < 30) && $this->checkPid()) {
        sleep(2);
    }

    if ($this->checkPid()) {
        // What, you're still alive? OK, time to say goodbye now. You had your chance...
        if (posix_kill($this->getPid(), SIGKILL)) {
            $this->log(sprintf('Sending SIGKILL to job "%s" (id: %s)', $this->getJobCode(), $this->getId()));
        } else {
            $this->log(sprintf('Error while sending SIGKILL to job "%s" (id: %s)', $this->getJobCode(), $this->getId()), Zend_Log::ERR);
        }
    } else {
        $this->log(sprintf('Killed job "%s" (id: %s) with SIGINT. Job terminated after %s second(s)', $this->getJobCode(), $this->getId(), $waitTime));
    }
```

The kill isn't working but i don't understand why the cron is still running in the first place!

Comment: Seems odd. `SIGINT` is assigned in Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_GracefulDead (line 22 ish) and provides a method in itself to call - not sure why it would be a string... perhaps you need to debug what `SIGINT` is at that point, because it shouldn't be a string

Comment: Yeah, what finally done but didn't really solve the problem was to disable Aoe then empty cron schedule in the database and turn off database backups in Magento Admin. Then I re-enabled Aoe.

Comment: I.e. You turned it off and on again?

Comment: No, I turned Aoe back on but for now I'm just going to manually back up the database.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late to answer, but I had the same problem as you did.

After some time of frustration I  went to the Connect Manager and uninstalled the extension, cleaned all cache, logged out and in and reinstalled it again. 
That did the trick for me, it is now running like it should.

I'm afraid I can't tell what was wrong with it, just that this worked for me.